# How to join between three tables using a subquery?

Tags: sql

I have 3 SQL tables:

```
tb1: name id and phone of student
tb2: courseName,courseNum
tb3: id,courseNum,grade
```

I need to find the name and courseName of student that their grade>80

I tried:

```
select * from tb1  where taz in(
    select taz from tb3 where grade>80
)
```

and

```
select courseNum from tb2  where courseName in(
    select * from tb3 where grade>80
)
```

It works but how can I join the 2 subquery?

Comment: Hint : **`JOIN`**

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb3 t3 INNER JOIN tb2 t2
ON   t3.courseNum = t2.courseNum
INNER JOIN tb1 t1
ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t3.grade > 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT c.name, b.courseName, a.grade
FROM tb3 a 
JOIN tb2 b ON a.courseNum = b.courseNum
JOIN tb1 c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE a.grade > 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the required result:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.CourseName, t3.grade from tb3
     INNER JOIN tb2 t2 ON t3.CourseNum = t2.CourseNum
     INNER JOIN tb1 t1 ON t1.id = t3.Id
where t3.grade > 80
```

Answer (score 0):

SMA answer is true, but need little modification. 
**first**: condition on second ON should be: t3.id = t1.id  
**second**: we want name and courseName.

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.coursename
FROM tb3 t3 INNER JOIN tb2 t2
ON   t3.courseNum = t2.courseNum
INNER JOIN tb1 t1
ON t3.id = t1.id
WHERE t3.grade > 80
```